# Closures and context in jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

I've reading a lot about closures and design patterns in jquery plugins (some contradictory things even), but I don't totally understand it...
I have this code, that is already working, but I donn't know if it's the best practice how I'm doing...

```
(function($) {

    var methods = { 
               method1 : function() { .... }
                  }

    return this.each(function() {

    $(this).change(function()
        {
        methods.method1.apply($(this));
        })

    });

})(jQuery);
```

My doubt is inside the event delegation function... Should I use a closures in there instead of apply? What would be the best practice? How should I define that closure? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you've got looks correct from here. (Though jQuery code is sometimes hard to verify by sight!)  When the event delegate is invoked, `this` will be the DOM element raising the event.  No need for a closure there.

Answer (score 0):

Besides what the other answers mention, `this.each` with only `$(this).change(...)` inside of it is redundant. If you change it to this:

```
// no this.each
this.change(function() {
    // ...
});
```

Then it should work exactly the same, but be more concise and arguably clearer.